# Safari is the only browser that doesn't update visibility css settings in this simple script until AFTER the file is uploaded. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

For some reason the following *very* simple code will not execute visibility setting in safari until *AFTER* the file is finished uploading or if a user doesn't put a file into the file input section.

This is the only browser it acts like this in.
Every other browser executes the visibility settings while the file is uploading. Please, can anyone explain why?

### ENTIRE SIMPLE PHP FILE CODE

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Our Industry Alpha 0.01</title>
      <script>
         function formcheck() {
            document.getElementById('i_submit').style.visibility='hidden'; document.getElementById('patience').style.visibility='visible';
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
         <input type="file" required>
         <input type="submit" style="visibility:visible;" value="Send" id="i_submit" onclick="formcheck();">
      </form>
      <div id="patience" style="visibility:hidden;">... UPLOADING ...</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of Safari? On `10.1.1 (12603.2.4)` I see the `UPLOADING` text.

Comment: Do you see the upload text *during* a file upload, or after the file is done?
I'm on Version 10.1.1 (12603.2.4) as well.

Comment: I see it after clicking the `Send` button for a second while the file is uploading.

Comment: Check this link to see a live version from my server:
http://www.ourindustry.net/Barebones/

Comment: I see it when I select a large file, perhaps too large to be uploaded. When I select a small file I don't see it however.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody that is so odd, it's not how it operates on my browser live from my server. Here's a link www.ourindustry.com/Barebones Would you mind seeing if it works the same way for you from your computer?

Comment: Also, this is saved as a .php file. Does it still operate the same way if you make it a .php file instead of an .html over on your server?

It has to be a .php file, because my actual site makes use of a lot of form return data. This is just a stripped down version to try to get down to why the visibility settings aren't working as intended.

Comment: It must be a server side issue for some reason?
Could someone, anyone, please try jumping to a broadcast version from my server and see how it executes live from the net?

[www.ourindustry.net/Barebones](http://www.ourindustry.net/Barebones)